# Initiation to Start Studying Vedas

Tags: vedas, brahmins, upanayanam

I have Learnt that a brahmin who doesn't learn Vedas is considered to be just a namesake brahmin

So considering a brahmin having had his upanayanam and his sacred thread (jandhyam),

1. Is there any upper limit for one to start studying vedas?
2. Does one require to study all the four vedas or the one the brahmin is related to? (brahmins are classified into rig veda, yajur veda..)
3. Is initiation (guru upadesam) necessary for vedas also?
4. I've read various answers stating only around 3% of original vedas are available now, then how could one possibly study vedas even if wanting to?

Ps. I'm not sure about the 4th question and I might be wrong as they might be still taught orally at some gurukulam s and would like to learn more about it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

*Chandogya Upanishad* VIII.15.1 says (Swami Gambhirananda translator):

> Brahma imparted this knowledge that was such to Prajpati, Prajpati (imparted it) to Manu, (and) Manu to the creatures. Having studied the Vedas in the teacher's house in accordance with the injunctions, during leisure after performing the duties to the teacher, he returns home from the teacher's house and takes up the duties of a householder. Then, he studies the scriptures in a sacred place, and makes his sons and disciples virtuous. Then, withdrawing all his organs into the Self, not injuring any creature other than what is perscribed in the scriptures, living in this way to the end of his life, he attains the world of Brahma. He does not return again, he does not return again.

And in the *Gita* 4.33-34, Krishna says (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> The Knowledge Sacrifice is superior to all material sacrifices, O scourcher of foes; for all works, without exception, culminate in Knowledge.
>
> Learn it by prostration, by inquiry, and by service. The wise, who have seen the Truth, will teach you that Knowledge.

Find your teacher, he will decide what is best as to how the vedas are imparted to you.

Answer (score 0):

1. No there's no strict limit.
2. No, not at 4 are required to be learnt. It's as per your wish.
3. Yes, it is required but it is already done if one has done Upanayan sanskar I think.
4. This is not true. Each Veda has multiple Shakhas. Each shakha is complete Veda by itself. Although, it is true that many Shakhas have gone extinct.

Comment: what do you think of the rig, sama, atharva, and yajur vedas that are available online? Are they the complete vedas or a portion of what's available

Comment: you should give references, otherwise your answer is just your opinion.